# Automatically import ICS to Google Calendar in Chrome on Linux

Tags: google-calendar, google-chrome, linux

This questions has been asked and answered before (e.g., [on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183711/google-calendar-as-default-handler-of-webcal-protocol-for-ical-ics-files)) but this doesn't work anymore, at least for me.

At some websites you can download ICS files for events. Is there a way in which these files are automatically imported to my Google Calendar in a single click, without having to download, go to Calendar, and import? I use Chromium (Chrome on Linux); at Settings -> Content Settings -> Protocol handlers I have enabled calendar.google.com for type "webcal". However, when I click on an ICS link my browser will just download the file.

A [very similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/automatically-open-ics-files-in-google-calendar) was asked before, but all the answers provided there only work on Firefox and/or Windows, while I use Chrome on Linux. Moreover, most answers seems to suggest I have to associate Google Calendar with Webcal type events, but as explained above, that is already the case in my setup.

Comment: The calify app is windows only; the Add to Google Calendar does not work for me (and judging by the two star rating, nor does it for many others); and all the other answers point to the handler setting, which I've already changed. Then there are a bunch of answers describing workarounds with emails, but I would think there should be a one-click solution for this. But given that linux seems to make things more complicated here, maybe the question should be moved to Ask Ubuntu

Comment: This question referred to a question from this site that was originally posted in [su] -> [Automatically open ICS files in Google Calendar](https://superuser.com/q/44191/152004). Opening files by double-clicking them is a feature that depends mainly in operative system settings, better to ask in [su] or [ubuntu.se].